# Ti.UI.iPad.createPopover sizing issue while orientation change occurs

Tags: uipopovercontroller, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, orientation-changes

Guys I am having problem of 'How to resize' popover on 'Orientation change'. Please take [Demo source-code](http://support.appcelerator.com/tickets/APP-186174/tickets).

Perform following steps to regenerate the problem:

- Download the attached source code, open and run it. :)

  => You will see a white window with just a single unnamed button at the top-middle of the window.
- Click on the button.

  => It will open the Popover control from the button. It contains a blank Tableview.
- Change iPad orientation from Portrait <-> Landscape.

  => Check that on orientation change, Popover size is being changed but the size of internal content (Tableview) is not being changed. So, It leaves blue blank parts around Tableview.

Please let me know if there is any answer to treat Popovers and win their hearts.

Thanks.

Comment: i can't download the source code, as appcelerator always shows the please Login screen, although i'm already logged in

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17595051/TestPopover.zip

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, rather then changing the size of the popover, change the height and width of the table and make the popover resize to it with a simple helper function (sth. like this:)

```
function resizepopover () {
    popover.height = popover.children[0].height;
    popover.width = popover.children[0].width   
    Ti.API.info("Popover Width: " + popover.width)
    Ti.API.info("Table Width:" + table.width)
    Ti.API.info("Popover height: " + popover.height)
    Ti.API.info("Table height:" + table.height) 
}
```

One thing, i noticed is, you create the Table and the popover inside the eventlistener,
which means every time you click the Label, a new Popover instance and a new table instance is created ( it should get garbage collected though, because you overwrite it each time, and there shouldn't be any reference anymore to the old one) but i would avoid it

And create the popover and the table outside the eventlistener.
And it the click events function you can just call the `show`method of the popover and
the `resizepopover`method.

```
var     popover = Ti.UI.iPad.createPopover({
        title : 'Search',
        arrowDirection : Ti.UI.iPad.POPOVER_ARROW_DIRECTION_UP,
        backgroundColor : 'white',
        layout: 'horizontal',
        height:"auto",
        width:"auto"
});
    var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        height:900,
        width:700
    });
    popover.add(table);
    
label1.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    popover.show({
        view : label1,
        animated : true
    });
    resizepopover();

});
```

in the Gesture event Listener set the tables width instead the popovers width

```
[...]
    if(root.ui.isPortrait || root.ui.isLandscape) {
            
        if(root.ui.isPortrait) {
            table.width = 600;

            table.height = 800;
            
            Ti.API.info('Portrait');
        } else {
            table.width = 800;
            table.height = 600;
            Ti.API.info('Landscape');
        
        }

        resizepopover();

    }
[...]
```

That's **one** Possible way,

I added a Resources.zip on [Dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/73856843/Resources.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Titanium has created ticket for this issue and it is their Internal error.

[Ticket Link](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-11004)